# Custom post type REST API custom endpoint for single post by ID

Tags: wordpress, api, rest, post, endpoint

I've created a WordPress custom post type, then I've created REST API custom endpoint to GET all the posts works well. Then I've created another custom endpoint to GET single post by ID. For example http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-json/lc/v1/cars/120

I have created a few posts, each time I change the ID at the end of the route to 118 or 116  it shows the same data for the latest post-ID 120. I need the relevant data to show based on the post ID, I would appreciate any kind of help. Thanks

```
public function rest_posts_endpoints(){

register_rest_route( 
        'lc/v1',
        '/cars/(?P<id>\d+)',
        [
            'method' => 'GET', 
            'callback' => [$this, 'rest_endpoint_handler_single'], 
        ]
    );
}

public function rest_endpoint_handler_single($id) { 

    $args = [
         'post_type' => 'cars',
         'id' => $id['id'],
    ];

    $post = get_posts($args);

        $data['id'] = $post[0]->ID;
        $data['slug'] = $post[0]->post_name;
        $data['title'] = $post[0]->post_title;
        $data['content'] = $post[0]->post_content;
        $data['excerpt'] = $post[0]->post_excerpt;

    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the WP_REST_Request $request to get the params passed.

```
public function rest_endpoint_handler_single(WP_REST_Request $request) { 

    $params = $request->get_query_params();

    $args = [
         'post_type' => 'cars',
         'numberposts' => 1,
         'include' => array($params['id']),
    ];

    $post = get_posts($args);

        $data['id'] = $post[0]->ID;
        $data['slug'] = $post[0]->post_name;
        $data['title'] = $post[0]->post_title;
        $data['content'] = $post[0]->post_content;
        $data['excerpt'] = $post[0]->post_excerpt;

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, could you help with the code above and make an example that I can use/test on my API?

Comment: Just replace the function rest_endpoint_handler_single with my code

Comment: I've added ur code above and it doesn't seem to make any difference? I can still see only the same post data.

Comment: Updated the code, please print $post to check the result first.

Comment: Excellent now it is working with the change of get_params(); 
Many thanks!! Updated the code too.